# Non-converging coefficients in hierarchial Bayes analysis of discrete choice

Tags: hierarchical-bayesian, conjoint-analysis

I am trying to analyse repeated responses from a discrete choice experiment.  The DCE had one continuous parameter and five 3-level categorical parameters.  I started with a multinomial logit and the model converged after 4 iterations.  The estimated dummy-coded coefficients are as follows, calculated relative to the middle level:

```
          Estimate   Pr(>|t|)    
LYg      0.0938639  < 2.2e-16 ***
Age.f1   0.2453775  1.521e-10 ***
Age.f3  -0.7102606  < 2.2e-16 ***
U0.f1    0.1518566  0.0002932 ***
U0.f3   -0.3249684  6.950e-12 ***
LE0.f1   0.0603195  0.1727848    
LE0.f3   0.0344367  0.4213998    
U1.f1   -0.4850307  4.730e-14 ***
U1.f3    0.3263514  1.083e-12 ***
Pats.f1 -0.1336018  0.0011723 ** 
Pats.f3  0.0131520  0.7579159
```

Now I'm trying the same analysis using hierarchial Bayes to incorporate individual heterogeneity, but the coefficient estimates, illustrated below, don't seem to be converging, even after 500k replications.  As I'm new to Bayesian analysis, I'm hoping someone can explain if this means that the HB model simply isn't going to converge, or if I need to run even more replications.  At what point should I conclude the HB model is futile?  I am also confused as to the size of the estimated coefficients -- as you can see in the figure, some of the unexponentiated coefficients are approaching 30!  Is this simply an artefact of a non-convergent model, or is there something else going on?

[image: HB coefficients after 500k replications]

FYI, I'm using the ChoiceModelR package in R, but I don't think that this is a programming question.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's not that the hierarchical model is hopeless; rather it appears that your sampling scheme needs some tweaking. Have you tried different proposal distributions for the metropolis step? What is the acceptance rate for these proposals? It should be around 15-30%. If it's not then it needs tuning. Also, i'd be very surprised if you needed anything like 500k iterations to determine if it's converging.

Comment: Thanks Jerad.  As per the [ChoiceModelR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ChoiceModelR/ChoiceModelR.pdf) documentation, "s = a scaling parameter that is used to adjust the standard deviation of random draws of unit-level parameters during the random walk metropolis step if the MCMC chain. Only specify s if you wish to keep a constant scaling parameter. (By default, s = 0.1 and is adjusted at each iteration to keep acceptance of random draws of unit parameters at approximately 30 percent.)"  I can confirm that the acceptance rate is ~30%.

Comment: Well without more information on your data and model specification it's hard to give advice. It usually requires a fair amount of experimentation to get samplers working in large models like this. The obvious adjustments, if you haven't already, would be your priors. Also, might be worth experimenting  with the variance of that metropolis proposal.